# How to prevent leverage browser caching?

Tags: .htaccess, iis, cache-control

I have used GTMetrix to test my site performance. Overall score is not that bad (93%) but there are some things that can be improved. One of the lowest scores I got is leverage browser caching. None of my `CSS/JS/IMAGE` files do not have expiration date set. I'm not familiar with leverage caching and how expiration can be set. After looking around I see that people use `.htaccess` file. I'm not sure where to create that file and what to add in the file in order to set expiration time/period. Here is example of my header files:

```
https://example.org/CSS/Login.css (expiration not specified)
https://example.org/JS/Login.js (expiration not specified)
https://example.org/animated_favicon1.gif (expiration not specified)
https://example.org/favicon.ico (expiration not specified)
https://example.com/images/basicrecblue.gif (expiration not specified)
https://example.com/siteseal/javascript/siteseal.js (expiration not specified)
```

The files above were identified with GTmetrix test. Can anyone help with some example on to implement `.htaccess` file? How to set expiration for each file type? I use ColdFusion on the back end and JS, HTML5 and Css with Bootstrap on the front end.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using Apache HTTPD as your webserver, you can simply set the cache control using the [`mod_expires` module](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_expires.html).

You can place instructions either globally using the config or for specific virtual hosts using `.htaccess` files. The content should look like:

```
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
    ExpiresActive on
    ExpiresDefault "access plus 30 seconds"
    ExpiresByType text/html "access plus 15 days"
    ExpiresByType image/jpg "access plus 1 months"
    ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 months"
    ExpiresByType application/javascript "access plus 1 months"
</IfModule>
```

Note that you might have to install/enable `mod_expires` first. You can find further instructions all around the internet.

Comment: Thank for explaining the steps. I will look around and try to test the code. I have one more question, would process be the same if I use IIS?